# What should I do if the IDE glitches

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

[IDE is glitching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSrXQ.gif)

I am on Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
Windows 10 10.0
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 4

When I try to type code:

1. Autocomplete does not activate
2. The cursor jumps around to random spots
3. My keyboard inputs are not registered sometimes

The only issue I have is in AndroidStudio. I have no issue using any other application on my PC. Is this an issue with my settings, program files, or something else.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you really just have 3 GB of physical RAM? The minimum requirement is 8 GB

Comment: No I have a 16 GB Ram, that information above is from the opening screen of Android Studio. There is a Copy About button that has that information stored for quick access.